# Reverse projecting screenspace coordinate to modelspace coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, coordinate-transformation

I am working on an Android Application in which a 3d scene is displayed and the user should be able to select an area by clicking/tapping the screen. The scene is pretty much a planar (game) *board* on which different objects are placed.
Now, the problem is how do I get the clicked area on the board from the actual screen-space coordinates?

I was planning on using [`gluUnProject()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html#gluUnProject%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int%29), as I have access to (almost) all the necessary parameters. Unfortunately I am missing the `winZ` param, and cannot get the current depth as the touch event is occurring in a different thread than the GL-thread.
My new plan is to still use gluUnProject, but with a `winZ` of 0, and then project the resulting point onto the board (the board stretches from `0,0,0` to `10,0,10` in model space), However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this?

I would be very happy if anyone could help me out with the maths needed to do this (matrices were never my strongest side), or perhaps find a better solution.

To clarify; here is an image of what I want to do:
[image]
The red rectangle represent the device screen, the green x is the touch event and the black square is the board (grey subdivisions represent a square of one unit). I need to figure out where on the board the touch has happened (in this case it is in square 1,1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve this by doing the following:

```
float[] clipPoint = new float[4];
int[] viewport = new int[]{0, 0, width, height};

//screenY/screenX are the screen-coordinates, y should be flipped:
screenY = viewport[3] - screenY;

//Calculate a z-value appropriate for the far clip:
float dist = 1.0f;
float z = (1.0f/clip[0] - 1.0f/dist)/(1.0f/clip[0]-1.0f/clip[1]);

//Use gluUnProject to create a 3d point in the far clip plane:
GLU.gluUnProject(screenX, screenY, z, vMatrix, 0, pMatrix, 0, viewport, 0, clipPoint, 0);

//Get a point representing the 'camera':
float eyeX = lookat[0] + eyeOffset[0]; 
float eyeY = lookat[1] + eyeOffset[1];
float eyeZ = lookat[2] + eyeOffset[2];

//Do some magic to calculate where the line between clipPoint and eye/camera would intersect the y-plane:
float dX = eyeX - clipPoint[0];
float dY = eyeY - clipPoint[1];
float dZ = eyeZ - clipPoint[2];

float resX = glu[0] - (dX/dY)*glu[1];
float resZ = glu[2] - (dZ/dY)*glu[1];
//resX and resZ is the wanted result.
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are working in 2D basically already, (I presume you mean your 3D board stretches from 0,0,0 to 10,10,0 (x,y,z).) you could translate and interpolate/extrapolate the 2D/3D space coordinates from your screen space coordinates without the gluUnProject(). You will need your screen resolution, and to pick the resolution of the 3D space grid you wish to convert to. If both the screen and 3D space origins are aligned (0,0 screen space is at 0,0,0 3D space), and your screen dimensions are 320x240, using your existing 10x10 3D grid, then 320/10 = 32, and 240/10 = 24, thus the screen space size of a single 1x1 area is 32x24. So if the user presses on 162, 40, then the user is pressing within ( 5, 1, 0) (162/32 >= 5 but < 6, 40/24 >= 1 but < 2 ) in the 3D space. If you need greater resolution than this you can select a higher 3D space grid resolution (i.e. using 20 instead of 10). You don't need to update the GL matrix to use this factor. Though it may make it simpler in some ways, I'm sure from a modeling perspective you would have additional work to do. Just be aware for a factor like 20, 1,3 would be at (.5, 1.5, 0). If your screen and 3D space origins are not already aligned will need to translate the screen space coord prior to this. If 0,0 screen space is 10,10,0, you will need to take your screen resolution and subtract the current point from it, making 0,0 into 320, 240 in this example, our example point of 162, 40, would be 158 (320-158 == 162), 200 (240-200 == 40).

If you'd like an overview of the projection matrix and how that all works, which could help you understand where to put the screen space dimensions in the unproject matrix, read this chapter of the OpenGL red book. http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it isn't that simple, the board is not perpendicular to the viewing direction, so a simple solution like this won't work.  
I updated the question with a simple graphic to help visualise the problem.

Comment: Oh, and I meant that the plane/ board is described in MODEL-space, not world (can't edit right now, writing on a phone)